# Keep only rows with same respective values

Tags: r

I have a data frame that's something like this:

```
  locID year effort1 effort2
1    L1 2000     iii       A
2    L1 2000     iii       B
3    L1 2001      iv       A
4    L1 2001     iii       A
5    L2 2000      iv       B
6    L2 2000     iii       B
7    L2 2001     iii       A
8    L2 2001     iii       B
```

I want to have pairs of `locID`'s from 2000 and 2001. BUT, I only want pairs that have the same values for both `effort1` and `effort2`. So, in this test data, I would only want to keep rows 1, 4, 6 and 8. This seems pretty complex, and not in the capability of `subset()`. Any suggestions?

My desired data frame from the one above

```
  locID year effort1 effort2
1    L1 2000     iii       A
4    L1 2001     iii       A
6    L2 2000     iii       B
8    L2 2001     iii       B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just want the rows in which locID, effort1  and effort2 agree.  You can get that with `duplicated`.

```
D1 = which(duplicated(df[,c(1,3,4)]))
D2 = which(duplicated(df[,c(1,3,4)], fromLast=TRUE))
Keep = sort(unique(c(D1, D2)))

df[Keep,]
  locID year effort1 effort2
1    L1 2000     iii       A
4    L1 2001     iii       A
6    L2 2000     iii       B
8    L2 2001     iii       B
```

A little explanation. `duplicated` gives all instances *except the first* for duplicated rows. When you use `duplicated` with `fromLast=TRUE` it gives all duplicates *except the last one*. You can put these together to get all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

A solution from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(locID, effort1, effort2) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
dt2
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   locID, effort1, effort2 [2]
  locID  year effort1 effort2
  <chr> <int>   <chr>   <chr>
1    L1  2000     iii       A
2    L1  2001     iii       A
3    L2  2000     iii       B
4    L2  2001     iii       B
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "  locID year effort1 effort2
1    L1 2000     iii       A
                 2    L1 2000     iii       B
                 3    L1 2001      iv       A
                 4    L1 2001     iii       A
                 5    L2 2000      iv       B
                 6    L2 2000     iii       B
                 7    L2 2001     iii       A
                 8    L2 2001     iii       B",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```